# JMESPath: How to filter based on key?

Tags: jmespath

Given the data

```
{
  "abc1": 0,
  "abc2": 1,
  "xyz1": 100
}
```

How can I get only the first two values, based on the fact that they start with 'abc'?

My first instinct was to use `keys()` and `values()`, but there is no `zip()` to put them back together.

Also, there is no `.key` or `.value` on a hash entry to look at one or the other to use with `startswith()`.

There is also no facility to transform a hash into a list of two-tuples, either; `to_array()` "*returns a one element array containing the passed in argument*", which does not help at all.

In `jq` I was able to get it with

```
$ jq 'to_entries | map(select(.key |startswith("abc")))'  /tmp/asdf.json
[
  {
    "key": "abc1",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "abc2",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

Note that the output format is immaterial to me; I can reformat it later.  What I need is the selecting behavior.